# Не срабатывает проверка состояния is(":hidden") с условием if

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#labels").hide();

    if($("#labels").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#tap, #page").slideDown(100);
    } else {
        $("#tap, #page").slideUp(100);
    }


    $(".label-button").blur(function() {
        $("#labels").slideUp(600);
    });
    $(".label-button").click(function() {
        $("#labels").slideToggle(600);
    });
});
</script>
```

Не срабатывает `is(":hidden")` для `#labels` с условием `if/else`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем тут проблема?

Прим.
Если `#labels` свернут, то показываем `#tap и #page`, - если он развёрнут, то сворачиваем `#tap и #page`.

Comment: вы же сначала скрываете '#labels' ... он всегда hidden

Comment: @eicto при открытии страницы мне требуется скрыть `#labels` и показывать его только когда нажата кнопка `.label-button`. Я пробовал всунуть проверку в функцию, но не получил ожидаемого результата, кроме того, пытался поставить проверку в конец кода, после функций... ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понял, зачем вы перенесли переключатель в `$(document).ready` (он срабатывает только один раз)

Как я понял вам нужно следующее -

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $labels = $("#labels").hide(),
    $tapAndPage = $("#tap, #page");

  if ($("#labels").is(":hidden")) {
    $tapAndPage.slideDown(100);
  } else {
    $tapAndPage.slideUp(100);
  }


  $(".label-button")
    .blur(function() {
      $labels.slideUp(600);
    })
    .click(function() {

      $labels.finish();
      if ($labels.is(":hidden")) {
        $tapAndPage.slideUp(100);
      } else {
        $tapAndPage.slideDown(100);
      }


      $labels.slideToggle(600);


    });
});
```

```html
<button class="label-button">Label button</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="labels">Labels</div>
<div id="tap">Tap</div>
<div id="page">Page</div>
```

идея в том, что перед тем как делать переключение и проверку, вам нужно сначала закончить предыдущую анимацию, чтобы элемент встал в определенное значение. если переключать сначала, то он всегда будет `!:hidden` т.к. в случае начала показа, вы уже сделали его visible, и меняете высоту, а в случае завершения - он еще никуда не скрылся.

Comment: благодарю за замечание. Да, вы верно реализовали, но когда активен `#labels` (то есть он показывается) и при этом нажать на любую область документа (просто кликнуть где-то чтобы кнопка потеряла фокус), то `#labels` сворачивается, но при этом должны разворачиваться `#tap и #page`, иначе страница становится пустой.

Comment: Тогда повесте на клик по документу проверку ещё, и stopPropagation в клике по кнопке сделайте

Comment: сделал, как вы подсказали, оказалось достаточно добавить в событие `$(".label-button").blur(function() {` строку `$tapAndPage.slideDown(100);`. К сожалению, я не смог понять для чего использовать `stopPropagation`, ведь добавив `event.stopPropagation();` в событие ``$(".label-button").click(function() {` я только отключил кликабельность кнопки. Вот пример с добавочной строкой: http://jsfiddle.net/fmgqacum/1/ Будьте добры!